# Ubuntu 18.04 not detecting Nvidia 1660ti gpu

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3000000-d3ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Under about info for graphics I get this llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0, 256 bits)

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 2):

You can install the correct proprietary Nvidia drivers by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then, reboot.